# Unresolved reference while accessing a member of an anonymous object

Tags: kotlin

I tried to create an object to group some variables, as it is typically done in JavaScript.

```kotlin
val authorization = object {
    val header = "Authorization"
}

fun main() {
    println ("${authorization.header}")
}
```

But this produces a [reference error](https://pl.kotl.in/MgjCLBIKA). The problem seems to be, that the type of `authorization` is `Any` and `Any` does not know `header`.

How to fix this?

BTW: [here](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/anonymous-inner-classes) is stated that this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the linked article failed to mention maybe is that this piece of code:

```
val obj = object {
    val question = "answer"
    val answer = 42
}
println("The ${obj.question} is ${obj.answer}")
```

is all inside the body of a single method. To be able to use anonymous objects like that from elsewhere they need to be private. So this would work fine:

```
private val authorization = object {
    val header = "Authorization"
}

fun main() {
    println ("${authorization.header}")
}
```

I see it does mention it in this related article in section 5 https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/anonymous-objects